# Why aren't delegate instances always cached?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Why does the C# compiler not create code which caches the delegate instance of `Action(SomeMethod)` in this case:

```
void MyMethod() {
   Decorator(SomeMethod);
}

void Decorator(Action a) { a(); }
void SomeMethod() { }
```

It does it only when `SomeMethod` is static:

```
static void SomeMethod() { }
```

**EDIT:**

To be clearer, let's take the following code:

```
class A {
    public void M1() {
       var b = new B();
       b.Decorate(M2);
    }

    public void M2() {
    }
}


class B {
    public void Decorate(Action a) {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling");
        a();
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the delegate allocation every time M1 is called, you can do it easily but it's quite ugly:

```
using System;

class A {
    Action _m2;

    public A() {
        _m2 = new Action(M2);
    }

    public void M1() {
       var b = new B();
       b.Decorate(_m2);
    }

     public void M2() {
     }
}


class B {
    public void Decorate(Action a) {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling");
        a();
    }
}
```

So my question was, what's the reason the compiler cannot generate a similar code? I can't see any side effects.

I'm not saying there's no reason, the people working on the compiler are much smarter than I will probably ever be. I'm only looking to understand which scenarios this won't work.

Comment: What test's have you done that say's otherwise?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ you can take a look with any decompiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't cache it for *instance* methods because the target instance is *part of the delegate*, and it *really* wants to use a static field for the cache. A static method call that doesn't capture any variables etc can be cached very cheaply, but it gets a lot more complex when state is involved, and `this` counts as state.

Yes, I suppose is could use an instance field to cache `() => this.SomeMethod()`, but frankly, `this` being the target is a relatively rare case and doesn't solve the general problem.

However, it also only does this for *lambda* syntax, i.e. even if `SomeMethod` is `static`

```cs
Decorator(SomeMethod); // not cached
Decorator(() => SomeMethod()); // cached
```

You can see the difference [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKF+gAgAUCBvfAFgIDkB7GAYQgGMALOAEwAoBKM3AoIAicZrQQQY4rgGVaYOAFk4MVrQ48A3LgC+lAkzade/HIIIixEqQi4mAvAD4CchctXreW3bn2XxktIoGGgEEHykYbyaBHo4wQBsBChUrkoqatwRsbpAA=)

This is because the difference is detectable (different object refs vs same object ref) and could *in theory* lead to different program behavior in existing code that used the original (non-lambda) syntax; so the cache provision has not to-date been applied retrospectively to the old syntax. Compatibility reasons. This has been discussed for years, though; IMO it is one of those things like the change to `foreach` L-value captures, that could probably be changed without breaking the world as much as we imagine.

---

To see the theoretical difference in an example based on the edited question:

```cs
using System;

class A
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new A();
        Console.WriteLine("With cache...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) obj.WithCache();
        Console.WriteLine("And without cache...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) obj.WithoutCache();
    }
    Action _m2;
    B b = new B();
    public void WithCache() => b.Decorate(_m2 ??= M2);
    public void WithoutCache() => b.Decorate(M2);
    public void M2() => Console.WriteLine("I'm M2");
}

 class B
{
    private object _last;
    public void Decorate(Action a)
    {
        if (_last != (object)a)
        {
            a();
            _last = a;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No do-overs!");
        }
    }
}
```

This currently outputs:

```
With cache...
I'm M2
No do-overs!
No do-overs!
No do-overs!
No do-overs!
And without cache...
I'm M2
I'm M2
I'm M2
I'm M2
I'm M2
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited it my answer, I added a more concrete example. I can't see any side effects of caching the delegate instance.

Comment: @DonBox when I'm at a PC (give me 10 minutes) I'll show how the code can be made to behave differently with/without the cache. It is a "but nobody would ever do that, surely?" thing, but there is a difference

Comment: @DonBox: Every instance created is larger. Caching using *static* fields has a linear cost on memory, in the number of delegates that are cached. Caching using *instance* fields is O(N*M) where N is the number of delegates and M is the number of instances. You may be creating millions of instances, each of which has 50 delegates, costing a huge amount of memory for potentially very little benefit, if any. That's a potentially very large and unpleasant side-effect.

Comment: "the cache provision has not to-date been applied retrospectively to the old syntax" - it's been applied retrospectively to the ECMA standard. That permission just hasn't been used within the compiler - yet.

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean, caching with a field like in my example? I didn't think that caching actually makes the object bigger, which obviously does, I only thought to avoid heap allocation. Which one is better it depends on how many times the function gets called I guess.

Comment: @DonBox: Yes, it depends on the balance between "the number of delegates cached" and "the number of times they're invoked per instance". With the compiler acting the way it does, you can always take steps to cache the delegate yourself for code that is called very often. If the compiler did it automatically, it would be harder to mitigate the cases where you *didn't* want it cached.

Comment: @JonSkeet  searching, I see a few hints at that in v5; interesting that they haven't leapt on it!

Comment: @DonBox see edit for an example of how the difference can be observed; emphasis: no *reasonable* code should be affected...

Comment: ...especially now that (as @JonSkeet notes) the specification makes the code above not just *unreasonable*, but *undefined* (comment split for notification purposes)

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell. I think JonSkeet 's observation is the key here, that if compiler cached the delegate like in my example, it would actually be less efficient because it would always bloat the object size, which is not always everyone wants

Comment: That's the kind of example I was looking Thanks @JonSkeet